# gksu: Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0

Tags: xorg, sudo, gtk, gksu, pkexec

All of the sudden gksu stopped working for me:

```
~$ gksu gparted

(gpartedbin:24252): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

The same happens with `gparted-pkexec`:

```
~$ gparted-pkexec 
No protocol specified

(gpartedbin:25454): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

What could possibly be causing this?

**I am not running this through SSH or VNC. This is localhost in a *normal* terminal window.**

Comment: You do not work in a graphical user interface or trying to run a program on a system (eg. via ssh) that no graphical interface provides.

Comment: @A.B. I should clarify that this is not via ssh. It's on local host in a very normal terminal window. Infact opening gparted from the application menu has the same result.

Comment: You shouldn't have to use `gksu` to run GParted. `gparted` uses polkit to get elevated privileges.

Comment: @muru when I run `gparted` without `gksu` I get `Root privileges are required for running gparted.`

Comment: Ok, try `gparted-pkexec` (without `gksu`) or  `gksu gpartedbin`.

Comment: @muru both of them give me the same Gtk-Warning as above. Same for `gksu gedit`. I have already formatted my disk through the command line. So it is not specifically gparted that I am concerned about.

Comment: What is the output of `echo "$DISPLAY"` ?

Comment: @TheSchwa `$DISPLAY` is `:0`

Answer (score 89):

If running Ubuntu 17.10 or newer, this issue can arise when an application has not been updated with full support for Wayland. As a workaround until the application is updated, you can run

```
xhost +SI:localuser:root
```

which will allow the `root` user to display applications on your desktop. Also see this Q&A for other possible workarounds: [Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w)

[source](http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/viewtopic.php?id=17446)

Comment: @MDMower Thx for editing, learned something new =)!

Comment: @pomsky Thx for adding the link ;)!

Comment: In 18.04 X-Org will be used again as default. So this problem should vanis then. [see](http://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver-will-ship-with-xorg-by-default-says-canonical-519564.shtml)

Comment: Same problem occurred with Ubuntu 20 and this solved it.

Answer (score 13):

Try running `xhost +localhost` in your terminal, and then running the command again. This lets all users on your system (i.e. root) open windows on your screen. Make sure to use +localhost and not simply +, as it's more secure to allow connections from only localhost than from anywhere.

To make this permanent, edit the `~/.xinitrc` file like this:

Run `gedit ~/.xinitrc`

Edit the file to look like this (it should be empty at the start):

```
#! /bin/bash
xhost +localhost &
```

Now save the file, log out and log in. Now everything should run just fine with sudo.

I can't reproduce your problem on 14.04, but this has worked for me in the past when sudo / gksu threw this error.

Sources:

1. http://www.nikhef.nl/~mjg/xhost_plus.html
2. https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/405624-sudo-doesnt-open-X-programs
3. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomXSession

Comment: This does work indeed. So does that mean its an access control restriction? Any ideas what the cause of this could be?

Comment: Yes, it's a security feature of X. It allows only connections from your user to the xserver until told otherwise, I think. I'm not super sure why it's required for some apps and not others, and I don't have a clue why it would be doing it for gparted of all things. Perhaps you were tinkering and tightened security somewhere?

Comment: Well its happening with all apps, even gedit.  Also I have noticed that it is only happening for one of my two users on the system, not the other. I've been tinkering with a lot of things, but not recently. A list of possible things that could cause this behaviour could help a lot.

Comment: OK, not sure the cause, but I do have a fix. You need to add the xhost command to the .xinitrc file for the user so it runs when you start the session.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Desperate was I but you saved my day!!!

Comment: This did not work for me... Any other idea?

Comment: This yields an error: **xhost:  unable to open display ""**

Comment: On [redis](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/4pzy7e/gparted_refuses_to_open_displaying_gpartedbin454/d9x4xyv/), it was suggested to use `xhost +local:`. After that I was able to launch gparted from the terminal, but using `xhost +localhost` didn't work.

Comment: Indeed!  `xhost +local:` fixed mine! It yields `non-network local connections being added to access control list` which is what is needed.

Comment: I get xhost:  unable to open display ""

Answer (score 8):

Execute the following in  your terminal:

```
nano /home/user/.bashrc # user = name of your user
```

Add the following line at the end.

```
export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority
```

Comment: Would be useful if you could add some explanation of how this solves the problem, and whether it has any adverse side effects?

Answer (score 2):

`xhost +` fixed my problem

but Be aware that `xhost +` completely deactivates authentication and allows everyone to access all application on your screen...

`xhost +si:localuser:root` seems to work similar with proper authentication

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by simply running in the terminal ,

```
sudo gparted
```

Looks like GTK+ root password dialog confused  with x server settings

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to possible issues that results in "Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0".

I got it after deleting `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`. Solution I know of as of now: restart, creating socket by `python -c "import socket as s; sock = s.socket(s.AF_UNIX); sock.bind('/tmp/.X11-unix/X0')"` from https://serverfault.com/questions/358866/create-unix-named-socket-from-the-command-line did not help to resolve the error.