# Regression? Ubuntu 17.10 gnome-shell starts instead of gnome-flashback

Tags: gnome, 17.10, login-screen, gnome-flashback

I have 17.10, been using `gnome-flashback` for quite a long time, since 16.04 and kept upgrading.

After installing latest updates, I can't make gnome-flashback to appear. In the login screen, I can choose Gnome Flashback - Metacity or Gnome Flashback - Compiz, but both, when chosen, end up displaying the new layout with "Activities" and the large icons panel on the left.

I have tried reinstalling `gnome-flashback` using

```
sudo apt-cache depends gnome-flashback | \
grep '[ |]Depends: [^<]' | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d ' ' | \
xargs sudo apt-get --reinstall install -y
```

which finished, but after restart, I still end up in that weird layout.
Also, when I lock the screen, it behaves like something was pressing enter every ~500ms, so it's not possible to enter the password.

What happened? Is that a bug? **Is Gnome Flashback supposed to work? What should I try to get it back?** Thanks!

*Update:* After reinstallation of `gnome-flashback`, some GTK apps wouldn't start, e.g. Synaptic said:

```
$ sudo synaptic
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(synaptic:3867): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

I was able to solve it as per [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614387/gksu-gtk-warning-cannot-open-display-0). I think I had this issue after upgrading to 17.10. Not sure if it is related to my issue above.

Comment: Yes, GNOME Flashback is supposed to work! Have you tried to create new user? If not try that to make sure it is not some configuration problem with your user. Otherwise have you checked log files?

Comment: Haven't tried other user.  I have checked dmesg. Which other would apply?

Answer (score 0):

> "when I lock the screen, it behaves like something was pressing enter every ~500ms, so it's not possible to enter the password"

I was able to fix this by uninstalling `lightdm` and `gdm3`, and then reinstalling both, and running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` which took me to a dialog where I chose `lightdm` over `gdm3` (which was used before). Now I am at least able to lock and unlock the system. Still no Flashback though.