# Gnome 3 - How to open application from the notification area tray icon?

Tags: indicator, notification, gnome-shell, panel-applets

Due to a [bug/glitch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1016988/regression-ubuntu-17-10-gnome-shell-starts-instead-of-gnome-flashback), I can't use Gnome Flashback for a while. I am forced to use the new Gnome 3 layout.

There are a few apps (Slack, Skype, Steam, KTorrent, Krusader, ...) that used to be minimized to a "tray icon" in the "task bar" or "notification area" or "indicator applet" or whatever, I am not quite sure about what the names are. It's the little icon somewhere in some bar which you can click to restore the app or show a menu.

In Gnome 3.26 (and later versions), there is no such area by default, and the apps, once minimized, disappear from GUI entirely. I can't see them anywhere, yet their process is running.

I am not going to criticize that decision (it's obviously a bad one :) ) and will skip to the questions:

1. How am I supposed to open such app?
2. How can I configure Gnome 3 to have that running apps icons area?
3. I have seen these [(K)StatusNotifierItem/AppInicator Support](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/) and [TopIcon Plus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/). Are these official? Or will it stop working in the next release as these workarounds tend to?

Comment: Re: (3) No, they're not official, but if unless you're always updating to the latest via a PPA, they're reasonably well-maintained and work with new releases.

Comment: The developer of "TopIcons Plus" has kinda killed the project: https://github.com/phocean/TopIcons-plus/issues/91

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install (GNOME) Tweaks by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Open Tweaks, under "extensions", there is "Ubuntu appindicators". Enable it and you should get that icons area.

If "Ubuntu appindicators" is not installed, install it first by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
```

Comment: Just a trivia "Ubuntu appindicators"  is a fork of "(K)StatusNotifierItem/AppInicator Support".

Comment: Yep, thanks for the note. I figured out because when both are installed, none of them work. I had to uninstall the (K)... one.