# Gparted not starting in my installed ubuntu 18.04 system

Tags: gparted

I tried running at command line by "sudo gparted" but in vain. The error message is

```
--Unit -.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
/usr/sbin/gpartedbin: error while loading shared libraries: libgtkmm-2.4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you tried to install gparted first ?  `sudo apt install gparted`

Comment: Install one of the packages you see with the terminal command `apt-cache search libgtkmm*`

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall libgtkmm-2.4-1v5`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/614387/gksu-gtk-warning-cannot-open-display-0

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I tried to reinstall libgtkmm but there were more broken libs, so I had to reinstall all of them:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libpangomm-1.4-1v5 libglibmm-2.4-1v5 libsigc++-2.0-0v5 libcairomm-1.0-1v5
```

And it works fine now.