# Can't use eog "Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused()"

Tags: gtk, eog

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.
I'm trying to view some images with `eog` and getting the error below

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(eog:736): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:38:12.816: cannot open display: :0
```

When I tried to run `xhost +si:localuser:root`,
I got this `xhost:  unable to open display ":0"`

Also `export DISPLAY=:1` didn't work

Comment: Have you tried all the answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/614387)?

Comment: @Kulfy Yes, I did. None of them worked for me.